# Chrome bolding fonts

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts

Brand new XP install, fonts are showing up bolded and crappy looking on every website in Chrome.  Example (IE/Chrome):

[image]

Any idea what's going on?

Edit: Should mention I have no extensions installed and no custom theme or font settings.

Comment: Brand new XP install = font smoothing disabled, most likely. Check your display properties and turn on ClearType.

Comment: I had font smoothing enabled, just hadn't turned on ClearType.  Looks better now.  I see people are voting for this question to be closed, if someone wants to move it and Marc if you want to post your suggestion as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brand new XP install = font smoothing disabled, most likely. Check your display properties and turn on ClearType.